# How does WhatsApp update the "last seen"?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Previously we were able to turn off mobile/Wi-Fi and turn on airplane mode, read the message, turn off airplane mode and turn mobile data / Wi-Fi on and that was the end of it. However, now it seems WhatsApp stores the information of the user opening the message even in offline mode to be sent later when it gets a connection.

My question is regarding last seen. What if I turn on airplane mode, read old messages that I have already opened. Close WhatsApp completely and turn airplane mode off. Will my last seen now be the time when I was reading old messages in airplane mode, or the last time I actually opened WhatsApp while connected to the internet. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: You probably know this already, but for those who don't, you can turn "Last seen" off under Settings > Account > Privacy.